# Is it necessary that if a limit exists at a point it should be also defined at that point?

Tags: calculus, limits, random

Say there exists a limit $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L$. Is it necessary that $f$ be defined at the point $x_0$ itself?
Well, what I think of it is that it's OK to be undefined at that point because I guess that won't cease the limit of that function to exist there would it?

Comment: You mean if it is necessary for $L$ to be a value of $f$?

Comment: Well it's something like if $L$ should be defined at the point $x_0$ ? Wait am re-editing my quest properly

Comment: $L$ being defined at the point $x_0$ doesn't make much sense. I suppose you mean does $f$ have to be defined at $x_0$? In that case, no, it does not. (Note that even if it were defined at $x_0$ but $f(x_0) \neq L$, it is still feasible for $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$. Hope that helps.

Comment: I made an [edit] to your post. Please check that I did not unintentionally change the content of the question.

Comment: no. it is not necessary. if $f$ is defined at $x_0$ and  $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L=f_{(x_0)}$, $f$ is continious at $x_0$

Comment: Then simply check out the definition of limit again; we only consider the behavior of $f$ near $x_{0}$.

Comment: @gebruiker thanks I was wrong in editing that

Comment: Technically speaking, the function $f(x) = 1$ defined on the domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is a counterexample which is not defined at $x = 0$ but clearly has a limit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"No", in a particularly strong sense: The very reason limits came into mathematics was to extract numerical values from difference quotients
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}}
$$
(which are, of course, algebraically indeterminate at $x_{0}$), in the limit as $x \to x_{0}$.

The formal definition of $L = \lim(f, x_{0})$ ("For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x - x_{0}| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$") *explicitly avoids* evaluation of $f$ at $x_{0}$, precisely because $f$ might be undefined at $x_{0}$.

Comment: +1, yeah, that's precisely what I was going to say. That's the whole point of limits, when there is no value (or a value cannot otherwise be calculated, or in strange cases where the value is separated from the nearby values.).

Comment: It is not "*precisely because f might be undefined at $x_0$*". It is *precisely because we are not interested in $f$ at $x_0$*.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: If we're going to split hairs, I'd argue my wording is correct _from the perspective of Cauchy_, writing down the definition for the first time. Your wording may be more natural from the perspective of a modern student learning about limits, but that's because Cauchy's definition is well-accepted.

Answer (score 8):

This is not at all necessary. For example: $$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x^2}x =0, $$
but $\left.\dfrac{x^2}{x}\right\vert_{x=0}$ is undefined.

If we do have that $f$ is defined at $a$ **and** $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, then $f$ is called [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) at $x=a$.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=L$ for a $f:D\to\mathbb R$ is defined as

> For all sequences $(a_n)$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = x_0$ we find $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = L$.

To guarantee that $L$ is uniquely defined we need at least one sequence $(a_n)$ of the domain such as $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = x_0$. Therefore $x_0$ need to be an accumulation point of the domain $D$.

**Conclusion:** $x_0$ does not need to be in the domain of $f$ but it must be an accumulation point of the domain.